# Can the code generated by a proc_macro be placed at the top level?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I am creating a proc_macro using `proc_macro_attribute` that creates a test module for the function it annotates. For example, if I have the following function:

```rust
#[my_proc_macro]
fn my_fn() -> i32 {
  42
}
```

The macro will create the equivalent to:

```rust
fn my_fn() -> i32 {
  42
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod __test_my_fn {
  use super::*;
  #[test]
  fn test_my_fn() {
    // Test code ...
  }
}
```

However, if the function I annotate is inside an `impl` block, the code expansion fails because Rust does not allow modules inside `impl` blocks.

Is there any way to place the test module at the top level (or outside the `impl` block if there is any)? The proc macro function only receives the `TokenStream` of the annotated function, so I have not been able to find out where this function is actually located within the syntax tree.

Comment: The workaround I usually see is to require another macro on the `impl`, like `#[my_proc_macro_impl] impl Foo { ... }` and since that macro is attached to the `impl` block, it can add code after it.

Comment: @cdhowie so the `my_proc_macro_impl` is the one actually doing the code generation, and `my_proc_macro_fn` is only used to tell `my_proc_macro_impl` that certain functions need to be read?

Comment: Yes. That's how e.g. serde `#[derive(Deserialize)]` works. You can put `#[serde]` macros on struct fields, but note there isn't actually a "real" `#[serde]` macro -- it's something the derive macro looks for and consumes itself.